# Send encrypted Service Bus messages with Azure API App

Tags: biztalk, public-key-encryption, azureservicebus, azure-api-apps

I would like to post brokered messages using an Azure API App to a Service Bus queue in Azure. The only 
problem I have with this is that the messages must be encrypted using asymmetric encryption
(public/private key). So the idea is that the API App sends encrypted messages using the public key 
to the Service Bus and later BizTalk polls the Service Bus and decrypts the messages with the private key.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: See an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l0xM0P that shows how to easily encrypt a message using AES encryption and then safely base64 encode it for transfer and then decode and decrypt to get the original message.

Comment: See http://chris.59north.com/post/Encrypting-messages-for-the-Windows-Azure-Service-Bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data encryption is not something that is built into Service Bus, but you could definitely encrypt the data on your own using a .NET library. This is really easy if your messages are below the max size (256 KB for standard messaging and 1 mb for premium messaging). Just set the message body to be the resulting encrypted message.